# Program to make non-metro apps large tiles in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

Is there a way to make non-Metro apps a large tile? For an example, I cannot make my Firefox tile a large tile. Is there a program that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not all apps provide the option for a larger tile in Windows 8. Most apps that offer a larger tile by default are informational apps such as the weather app or the mail app. The larger tile allows these apps to display more information at a glance. An app tile like Firefox has no extended function by being larger so this is generally not available from my knowledge.

In short, even if such a program exists that can bypass this I am unsure of the benefit that a larger tile for an app like Firefox would bring other than appearing visibly larger.

With greater tile customization it is possible in [Windows 8.1](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/operating-systems/windows-blue-update-to-build-on-and-improve-windows-8-1131737) to make them even larger than currently possible. Even so, this may or may not be available for non informational third party apps like Firefox.

Comment: Would OblyTile be able to bypass this? I just find it hard to believe how someone hasn't found a way to do this yet...